# Illegal invocation when using toArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I don't have very much to my code but I seem to be getting `Illegal invocation` with my `order` variable - works fine and shows in `console.log` if I comment it out

```
$('body').on("click", "#brands_by_category_submit_btn", function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();               
                var self       = $(this);
                var order      = $(".order").toArray(); 
                var id         = $("#manID").data("id");
                var brand_name = $("#brand_name").data("id");
                var data       = grabData(true);


                if(data.length)
                {
                    var data_array = { 
                        id : id,
                        brand_name : brand_name, 
                        cat_id     : data,
                        order      : order, 
                        state      : 1
                    };

                    var url = $("#brands_by_category_submit_btn").data("url");

                    //console.log(data_array);  
                    ajaxCall(url, data_array);

                    alert("Categories Updated");

                }   
            });
```

**AjaxCall:**

function ajaxCall(url, data_array, div_id, callback_fn) {

```
    return $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:url,
        beforeSend: function(){
             $("#" + div_id).html("<img src='http://www.#.co.nz/files/large/ajax-loader.gif' alt='Loading..' title='Loading..'/>");
        },
        data:data_array,
        complete:function (data) {
           $("#" + div_id).html(data.responseText);

           if(callback_fn != null)
           {
               eval(callback_fn + '()');
           }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Same problem with `$(".order").get();` ?

Comment: @Johan yes it is sadly

Comment: Is the fault within ajaxCall() ?

Comment: What do you expect from your `toArray` call that would make it parse able as POST data? It's an array of regular HTML objects.

Comment: I was thinking JSON.stringify() might choke on some of that, too, and that is often a step in serializing data for an AJAX call.

Comment: @Jess McKenzie If you can identify a line or lines of this code that throws the error, or causes it not to be thrown when commented out, that would be useful.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I am trying to create an array of items within the `order` .class

Comment: @paul its the var order line

Comment: @JessMcKenzie But then you send **that** array as post data? Do you expect the post data to magically convert an HTML object into a serialized string?

Comment: @h2ooooooo no i would run the array through a foreach in the php controller

Comment: Show your `ajaxCall`. You're probably trying to push jQuery objects, not serialized to JSON or whatsoever.

Comment: What could be wrong with `$(".order").toArray()` ?  -- if jQuery wasn't loaded, you should have had problems earlier.  If the class is empty, you get an empty array.  I think it must be what happens later.

Comment: @JessMcKenzie But you can't do that. When post data is being sent, it's all simple converted to a string. `{ foo: 'bar', oof: 'rab' }` gets converted to `foo=bar&oof=rab` and you can't simply convert an HTML object to `htmlobject=[htmlobject,10,20]` etc. Would you expect all data of that to be there? `jQuery` is a **client side technology** and you need to send a **serialized** string to your PHP. Are you perhaps trying to create a string of the **texts** in the objects and not the HTML element itself?

Comment: @h2ooooooo I am trying to pass input boxes into an array by class to feed into the controller

Comment: @JessMcKenzie Okay, but I still don't think you understand. An **HTML element** cannot be converted to anything else than the string `HTMLElement` at **best**. You probably want to loop through it in JS, and **then** post either an array of a concatenated string with ajax.

Comment: I think /h2o+/ has a good grasp of the problem.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Can you please provide an example

Comment: Something like `var order = []; $("div").each(function() { order.push($(this).text()) });` but with `$("div")` being your order elements? That would POST an array (which would get converted to `foo=[1,2,3,4,5,6]` instead as a string).

Comment: @h2ooooooo Can you provide an example so I can accept it plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're converting an array of HTML elements into POST data which simply isn't possible. You should instead loop through your elements and grab their `.text()` property:

```
var self       = $(this);

var order      = []; //or "new Array()". Whatever you prefer for readability
$(".order").each(function() {
    order.push($(this).text());
});

var id         = $("#manID").data("id");
var brand_name = $("#brand_name").data("id");
var data       = grabData(true);
```